# singular or plural form in the following sentence

Tags: grammatical-number

We use the aforementioned eight factor models and report the **numbers** of significant factor coefficients of the different factor models in Table 2.

OR

We use the aforementioned eight factor models and report the **number** of significant factor coefficients of the different factor models in Table 2.

The context of the sentence is that I ran 25 regressions using 8 models, respectively. Every right-hand variable have 25 coefficients among which some are not significant. I need to report the number of significant coefficients for such a variable.

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: If you delete "number of" entirely, this problem goes away.

Comment: @tchrist No. I wanna report the number of significant coefficients rather than coefficients. I ran 25 regressions using 8 models, respectively. Every right-hand variable have 25 coefficients among which some are not significant. I wanna report the number of significant coefficients for such a variable.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry for this inappropriate word I used. I am not a native English speaker and thank you for pointing our my mistake. Is it because the word is only used in oral English.

Comment: That's correct: it's how we pronounce what we write as *want to*. It’s what’s called [*eye dialect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect), and it makes you look either uneducated or else pretending to be so, like some yokel in a fiction novel that the author is trying to make sound like... well, a yokel. *Aikin ride in I’d aleck thachool jis nev argit* and then where we will all be? I strongly advise that when you're ***writing*** English, you use **only** standard ***written*** English to do so — and *forra longa time den ya think ya hafta, k?*  It’s only appropriate in some places.

Comment: @tchrist OK. I have learned a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

*numbers* would imply the values of the coefficients, so would the sentence (as per @tchrist's comment) without *numbers of*.

*number* would imply you count the coefficients (the magnitude of the coefficients bag, the plurality, to be precise). You don't want to count all eight models at once, but that may be gleamed from context. If you want to be precise, you may use "*each*".

You could report the *number**s***, it's not a bad idea unless you have too many coefficients to list, because small set sizes are easier to recognize in graphics (4 to 7 items can be counted with one gaze).

Comment: correction: "*confusion*". You are welcome.